# Numbers as objects

Tags: java, object-oriented, entity-component-system

Instead of

```
this.getValue();
```

I thought it would reduce duplication I had number objects such as

```
this.value.get();
```

I have numbers that need min/max specified as well as other functionality and this is the most time efficient / centralized way I could come up with.

These objects are used in composition and declared in the constructors only

```
class Num{
    constructor(value){ 
        this.max = false;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Get, set, add, substract, multiply, divide and more functions

    get(){
        return this.value;
    }

    set(v){
        if(this.getMax() && v > this.getMax()){
            v = this.getMax();
        }

        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
this.value = new Num(50);
```

Is this ugly and unrecommended way of coding?

Not all numbers are objects, would that make the code inconsistent?

If so, would adding aliases improve the readability?

Example:

```
getValue(){
    this.value.get();
}

setMax(max){
    this.value.setMax(max);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this approach (`this.value.get();`), you end up exposing implementation details of your class.

Imagine that, due to a change in requirements or whatever, the field `value` now needs to be computed on the fly based on some other attributes.

With a traditional getter, you can simply replace the implementation without changing the interface:

```
public Num getValue() {
    return this.foo * this.bar;
}
```

All the callers of `getValue` would have the new functionality without needing to change their code.

---

As a side note, languages like c# and python have something called `properties` that tackle this exact problem.
They default to something similar to public fields, but allow you to change how you get or set a field without changing the interface.

Comment: Good point, it would be a huge problem if the project became big enough. What about aliases like I mentioned?  I would keep number objects to not duplicate functionality and improve readability in my classes, but have functions like getValue() that would be public while the number functions would be private. Is that totally a bad idea?

Comment: Sure, encompassing common logic in a single place is usually a good idea and OOP concepts can extend that very far. Creating a custom class for numbers is probably unnecessary, but the general idea still holds.. I'll just try to rephrase my advice above: try to keep your interface and implementation as separate as possible. Think about what is the responsibility of an object and how it will be used. How it actually achieves this should be considered private.

Comment: Sound advice, I see what you mean and I'll work to make it clear and seperated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You usually aren't supposed to create a new class just to enforce something. You should instead do it in the getters and setters of the property. Here is an example of what I'm talking about (in Java but you can do it pretty much in any oop language)

```
public void setNumber(int value) {
    if (value > max) value = max; // or throw a exception

    this.number = value;
}
```